# Transition after a certain period of time in state machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timer, state-machine, transition

I am currently developing a Rails app and I am using the state_machine gem to guide the customer through a complex process.

At multiple states of the process, I need to trigger events after a certain period time. For instance, if the customer hasn't confirmed he received his order after 5 days I'd like to automatically send him an email and enter in a parcel tracking process.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base



    state_machine :initial => :confirmed do

        after_transition :on => :not_received_by_5_days, do |order, transition|
            order.send_email
            order. .....
            order. .....

        event :customer_confirmation do
            transition :confirmed => :order_received
        end

        event :not_received_by_5_days do
            transition :confirmed => :parcel_tracking_process
        end

        def send_email
            blabla
        end
    end

end
```

**Editing after testing my previous solution:**

How can I trigger transition after a certain period of time?

Thank you,

Clément

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To break the solutions into two major groups, you can:

1. Use a Ruby/Rails queueing solution, like [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), or [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org); or,
2. Use a cronjob.

The former tends to make the most sense if you're already using one of those tools or know you're going to end up using one of them. All of them require a fairly substantial amount of effort to get going. Resque and Sidekiq require configuring a Redis server while DelayedJob uses your existing database. Resque additionally requires a plugin to schedule jobs, while DelayedJob and Sidekiq natively support scheduling a job. All three require creating job models and configuring workers to run.

The latter's pretty simple assuming you have cron access. Write yourself up a script in Ruby, and schedule it to run automatically via cron.

I haven't used state_machine for a while, but this should work (if not, it gets the idea across):

```
#!/usr/bin/env /path/to/project/bin/rails runner
Order.where(state: 'confirmed').where("created_at <= #{5.days.ago}").find_each do |o|
  o.not_received_by_5_days
end
```

What's going on here? As soon as our Order object is created, it enters the `confirmed` state. So to find the orders that need a little nudge, we can run an ActiveRecord query to find orders in the `confirmed` state that are 5+ days old. We then iterate through each record and fire the not_received_by_5_days event.

The whole thing is managed by the Rails runner, which loads up your Rails environment and executes your script's code there (just like using the Rails console, but without human intervention).

Run by cron once or twice a day (or more frequently if you want the emails to go out more frequently), the script will find every unattended order that's at least 5 days old and move it through your workflow. Since your code (should) move people to a new state once the not_received_by_5_days event fires, they'll no longer show up in subsequent script executions and will only receive one reminder.

Comment: Thank you once more colinm!
Using a cron job will be the solution for me!
I've found some interesting documentation on [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised) about cronjob!
Thanks once more!

Answer (score 0):

as another option, state_manager(https://github.com/ghempton/state_manager) gem integrates with delayedjob and allows triggering transition after some time passes automatically:

```
class UserStates < StateManager::Base
  state :submitted do
    event :activate, :transitions_to => :active, :delay => 2.days
  end

  state :active
end
```